# Options for Google Maps over SSL

Tags: google-maps, iframe, ssl, https

We recently discovered that the Google Maps API does not play nicely with SSL.  Fair enough, but what are some options for overcoming this that others have used effectively?

> [Will the Maps API work over SSL (HTTPS)?](http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=65301&topic=10945)
>
> At this time, the Maps API is not
>   available over a secure (SSL)
>   connection. If you are running the
>   Maps API on a secure site, the browser
>   may warn the user about non-secure
>   objects on the screen.

We have considered the following options

1. Splitting the page so that credit card collection (the requirement for SSL) is not on the same page as the Google Map.
2. Switching to another map provider, such as Virtual Earth.  Rumor has it that they support SSL.
3. Playing tricks with IFRAMEs.  Sounds kludgy.
4. Proxying the calls to Google.  Sounds like a lot of overhead.

Are there other options, or does anyone have insight into the options that we have considered?

Comment: Google Maps API Premier costs you 10K per year. Comment on the issue! Together we might be able to convince Google: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=591

Comment: Hi Brad. Time to accept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437/options-for-google-maps-over-ssl/5337403#5337403 instead? Google Maps now works with SSL for free.

Comment: Google recently released Maps API for secure websites: [Maps APIs over SSL now available to all](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html )

Comment: "Google Maps now works with SSL for free" Can Android App making SSL connections over Map API V2 also benefit from this news?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd agree with the previous two answers that in this instance it may be better from a usability perspective to split the two functions into separate screens. You really want your users to be focussed on entering complete and accurate credit card information, and having a map on the same screen may be distracting.

For the record though, Virtual Earth certainly does fully support SSL. To enable it you simple need to change the script reference from http:// to https:// and append &s=1 to the URL, e.g.

```
<script src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

becomes

```
<script src="https://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.1&s=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Their SSL is not valid though, they use mixed content as well.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to this

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html

Haven't tried migrating my SSL maps (ended up using Bing maps api) back to Google yet but might well be on the cards.

Comment: Seems to be working great! Documentation: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#HTTPS

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a buisness requirements/usability issue - do you have a good reason for putting the map on the credit card page? If so, maybe it's worth working through some technical problems.

You might try using [Mapstraction](http://www.mapstraction.com/), so you can switch to a provider that supports SSL, and switch back to Google if they support it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with your first solution. This allows the user to focus on entering their credit card details.

You can then transfer them to another webpage which asks or provides them further information relating to the Google Map.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a [Google Maps API Premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) customer, then SSL is supported.  We use this and it works well.

Prior to Google making SSL available, we proxyed all the traffic and this worked acceptably.  You lose the advantage of Google's CDN when you use this approach and you may get your IP banned since it will appear that you are generating a lot of traffic.

Comment: Google Maps Premier is great, if you work for a larger company with 10k just sitting around. If you're like me, you're sort of out of luck it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting SECURITY ALERT on IE 9 while displaying Google maps, use

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&hl=en&tab=wl&z=6&sensor=true&key=<?php echo $key;?>
" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Links that promote your personal blog are frowned upon here. Instead, I've taken the content of your blog post and placed it within your answer. Please do this in the future for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I 've just removed the http protocol and it worked!

From this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```