# Map controls for sites running https

Tags: google-maps, ssl, https, bing-maps

A team I work with is currently in an unfortunate situation. They've spent a lot of time integrating the google map control on their site but they didn't discover that to run google maps on a https site you must license the control (and it isn't cheap) and the same goes for bing maps.

So my question is do you know of any cheaper/free map controls like google or bing maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't they put the google maps part on a non-secure page or frame? The google licence says that you must have it on a publicly accessible site to benefit from the free version of the licence, so even on a http site, you may still need to pay for the data.

All other mapping tools are dependant on the expensive map source data, so you'll not find any. The exception is [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) which uses community-supplied map data.

Comment: The site is publicly available. The short answer as to why we just can't use it on a non-secure site is that it would require a major restructuring of a bunch of sites, not just this one, to do so.

Comment: When I say "is publicly available", I mean "will be ...", as in we havn't released yet.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)

Answer (score 5):

In version 3 of the API, HTTPS support is now free.

Answer (score 2):

MapQuest's API allows SSL usage through the free license.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437/options-for-google-maps-over-ssl/20612#20612) post - you can use Bing maps over ssl with no problems, and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the danish users I found the following [VisKort](http://www.softwareborsen.dk/projekter/softwarecenter/viskort) component on SoftwareBørsen. It looks like it is based on OpenStreetMap, but I'm not sure.