# Embedding Google Maps over SSL

Tags: google-maps, ssl

I'm embedding a map on a page via https URLs but I'm still seeing resources loaded via `http://` in the Net tab in Firefox.  I've done some Googling and everything I'm finding is about the Google Maps API.  Has anyone gotten this to work over SSL before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Options for Google Maps over SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437/options-for-google-maps-over-ssl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html

Ismail is right - check out the thread on Options for Google Maps over SSL. 
Personally I had to migrate my Google maps to Bing for the https connection api.

The Google map apis should now be available over https - but at least from my point of view there may be clashes with the licence (not-for-profit organisation but the site is access protected).

Have a look at [Mapstraction](http://www.mapstraction.com/) if you want to swap map interfaces around to try them out.